# NoClassDefFoundError on MongoCustomConversions while upgrading springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions

I am upgrading springboot to 2.6.6,springframework to 5.3.18, I have also added spring-data-mongodb dependency version : 3.3.3

Detailed stack trace :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoCustomConversions(MongoDataConfiguration.java:63)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor342.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ... 75 more

spring dependencies in pom are :

> 

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    and in properties file I have added :

    <spring-data-commons.version>2.6.0</spring-data-commons.version>
    <spring-data-mongodb.version>3.3.3</spring-data-mongodb.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.6.6</spring-boot.version>
    <spring.version>${spring-boot.version}</spring.version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi This error got resolved after adding the following dependency :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version> 
 </dependency>
```

this is the latest bson version, you can add a version compatible with your other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please list all the dependencies in your program, with below snippets from my pom.xml, I am able to use MongoCustomConversions without any issues.

Spring boot: 2.6.6
Spring framework: 5.3.18
spring-data-mongodb: 3.3.3

```html
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  ....
  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Added spring dependencies in question

Comment: I can't reproduce with dependencies you have posted, it works fine for me. But one of the clue would be:


`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoCustomConversions(MongoDataConfiguration.java:63) at         `                         




I just checked and MongoDataConfiguration class in sprin-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar is just 50 lines long, so some transitive dependancy somewhere is loading some old jar in your case probably?